# How long would it take for the solar core to destroy Earth?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, astrophysics, estimation, stars

If Earth were at the middle of the solar core, how long would it take to destroy the planet?

Furthermore, how would the planet be destroyed?

To consider the planet to be destroyed, it must be ripped apart in some senses. I'd imagine that the Surface of the Earth would continuously melt and disperse into the sun, until nothing is left.

I've done some research and found that the Sun's energy output is roughly e26, and the gravitational binding energy of earth is e32. So that suggests it would take at least e6 seconds for the Earth to be destroyed.

Comment: The density is also around `160g/cm^2`  Earth is about 5.5 on average

Answer (score -4):

Disclaimer: I'm no expert. But, I've just imagined your scenario via a thought experiment, and I think Earth would be vaporised in a matter of seconds or minutes.

If not that, then surely Earth would be very quickly rendered into molten rock plasma (if indeed there is such a thing).